# Quero colocar 2 exceções para o meu programa validar dados

Tags: python, python-3.x, validação

```
a =  ('''
Escolha a conversão que você deseja realizar:
1) Celcius-Fahrenheit
2) Fareheint-Celcius
3) Celcius-Kelvin
4) Kelvin-Celcius
5) Fahrenheit-Kelvin
6) Kelvin-Fahrenheit
''')

try :
   a = int(input(a)) and (a) < 7 and (a) > 0

except ValueError:
    print ("Escolha uma opção válida")
```

Estou tentando fazer um programa que converta uma temperatura de uma escala para outra.

Mas toda vez qeu tento rodar as duas exceções principais do programa (não rodar letra como opção e ter um valor de 1 à 6 para o usuário escolher). Está dando este erro no VSC :

> **TypeError**: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'*.

Gostaria de saber o porquê disso e  como fazer o programa funcionar com essas duas excessões

Comment: Você não pode comparar stings com inteiros `(a) < 7` e `(a) > 0`

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 4):

Acho que é isto que quer fazer:

```
try:
   a = int(input(a))
   if a > 0 and a < 7:
       print ("o valor deve ser entre 1 e 6")
except ValueError:
    print ("Escolha uma opção válida")
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ans1tl). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ValidationRangepy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/ValidationRange.py).

O que você quer fazer é diferente de validar a entrada de dados. Na verdade eu acho um erro validar a entrada de dados lançar uma exceção quando o dado é inválido, mas foi assim que Python decidiu ser e é como deve fazer. Já validar a faixa o mais fácil é fazer um `if` mesmo.

Dá para fazer diferente. Dá para fazer o `if` lançar uma exceção e cair no `except`, mas eu não faria isso porque o motivo é outro, é mais lento, e a mensagem mais adequada para orientar é outra.

Uma outra forma é evitar a exceção, mas aí teria que escrever um código que faça a validação da entrada do dado e retorne um booleano (o que eu acho Python deveria ter feito para este caso), mas dá muito trabalho, é fácil fazer errado e não vale o esforço.

O reaproveitamento da variável para coisas distintas nessa casos não causa erro, mas não deveria ser feito. Na verdade nem precisa mesmo de uma variável no primeiro caso, mas entendo porque fez, mas chame ela de `mensagem`. E `a` poderia ter um nome um pouco melhor, nem que seja `valor`, já dá uma semântica melhor, vai acostumando escrever código mais legível.