# Como fazer uma função com validação de dados de Python? do tipo Try

Tags: python

1. Quando eu faço esse codigo fora de uma funçao ele funciona, agora quando eu faço com função ele me retorna 0.

   ````
    ```
    def validacao(x):
        try:
            x = int(input())
            band = 1
        except ValueError:
            band = 0
        while band==0:
            print("Somente números!")
            try:
                x = int(input())
                band = 1
            except ValueError:
                band = 0

    print("1 - Inserir registro de um cliente")
    print("2 - Listar os registros dos Bebes")
    print("3 - Buscar pelo registro de um Bebe")
    op = 0
    validacao(op)
    ```
   ````

Comment: Esse código muito confuso e não faz sentido, faça algo mais simples: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/456654/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/428367/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/433051/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/433468/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/451936/101

Comment: A função `validacao` não possui um retorno? E, por favor, reveja a indentação do seu código na pergunta. Atualmente há um `while band == 0` que geraria infinitas mensagens "Somente números" e travaria seu programa.

Comment: Sobre o while, ele tem um input embaixo depois do try, pra validar mais uma vez, ele nao fica gerando infinitas mensagens. Quando eu faço essa validação sem estar dentro deu uma função ela funciona. Obrigado

Comment: @VictorHugo, não sei se foi um erro ao copiar aqui mas parece que seu código tem um problema de indentação. O try e o excpet deveriam estar dentro do while, senão o código não faz sentido.